# $x+y-1$ divide $n$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

Find all $n>1$  odd number s.t. for any $x, y$ divisors of $n$ with $gcd(x,y)=1$ we have $x+y-1$ divide $n$.

It's intuitive that $n$ is of the form $p^k$ with $p$ prime.

My idea:

I consider $n=p_1^{a_1}\cdot p_2^{a_2}\cdot ...\cdot p_k^{a_k}$ with $p_1<p_2<...<p_k$.

$k\geq 2$

I let $x=p_1$ and $y=p_2^{a_2}\cdot...\cdot p_k^{a_k}$.

But $p_2,...,p_k$ don't divide $x+y-1$ because of minimality of $p_1$. So $x+y-1$ should be a power of $p_1$. But this is not necessary false and I am stuck.

Comment: Any $n$ of the form $p^a$ is an example.  The only relatively prime divisors of $n$ must be of the form $p^b,1$ for $b≤a$ and in each such case $p^b+1-1=p^b$ which is a divisor of $n$,

Comment: If we drop the restriction that $n$ is odd, then $n$ does not need to be a prime power; $12$ also works. So you'd want to use the parity of $n$ somehow to prove that prime powers are the only examples. (Possibly $12$ is the only unusual case, though.)

Answer (score 1):

Only prime powers can satisfy the desired hypothesis.
As you rightly observed, if $p$ is the smallest prime factor of $n$, with $p^m\mid\mid n$, and $n$ is *not* a prime power, then with $x=p$ and $y=np^{-m}$ such that $(x+y-1)\mid n$, it follows that $x+y-1= p^l$ for some natural number $l\le m$; equivalently,
$$n=(1-p+p^l)p^m\,.$$ Clearly, we must have that $l\ne 1$, thus in particular $m\ge 2$. We claim that we can find a different pair $(x,y)$ failing the desired hypothesis. This time, let $$x=p^2\,,~\,~\,~\,~\text{and}\,~\,~\,~\,~y= 1-p+p^l\,.$$
In particular, $n=xyp^{m-2}$. It is now not difficult to check that $(x+y-1)\nmid n$; indeed, a common prime factor of both $n$ and $x+y-1=-p+p^2+p^l$ must either divide $y-1$ and $x$ (which is simply $p$) or must divide $y$ and $x-1=p^2-1=(p+1)(p-1)$, which, because $p$ is odd, cannot exist because it would necessarily be *smaller* than $p$, contrary to the minimality of $p$. We therefore conclude that if $(x+y-1)|n$, then $p$ is the only prime factor of $x+y-1=p(-1+p+p^{l-1})$, which is blatantly absurd!

**Remarks**

The argument shows that if one allows for $n$ to be even, the last part would require that $p=2$ such that $(2^{l-1}+1)|(2^l-1)$. This is only possible if $l=2$, leading to the only potential even non-prime power cases satisfying your hypothesis as $n\in\{2^{m}\cdot 3:m\ge 2\}$. Of these, letting $x=2^m$ and $y=3$ shows that necessarily $m=2$, and thus $n=12$ is the only admissible solution.

Comment: Why is it not possible that $x+y-1=p^l y_1$ where $y_1 > 1$ and $y_1 | y$? Thanks.

Comment: @Neat Math: I presume this is with regards to the initial assumption that $x=p$ and $y=np^{-m}$. For that, it is not possible because $p$ is smallest prime factor of $n$ and as such any common prime factor of $n$ and $x+y-1$ must necessarily be $p$; hence once we require that $(x+y-1)\mid n$, then $x+y-1$ is bound to be a prime power of $p$.

Comment: @NeatMath Note with $x = p^2$ and $y = 1 - p + p^{l}$, then $x + y - 1 = p(p^{l-1} + p - 1)$. With the requirement $x + y - 1 \mid n \implies p(p^{l-1} + p - 1) \mid (1 - p + p^{l})p^m$, since $\gcd(p^{l-1} + p - 1, p^m) = 1$, then $p^{l-1} + p - 1 \mid 1 - p + p^{l}$. However, then $p^{l-1} + p - 1 = 1 - p + p^{l} \implies p^{l-1}(p-1) = 2(p-1) \implies p^{l-1} = 2$, which is not possible for odd prime $p$. This means there's a $q \gt p$ where $-(p-1) + p^{l} = q(p^{l-1} + (p-1)) \implies (q-p)p^{l-1}+q(p-1)=0$, which is also not possible.

Comment: @NeatMath In my comment above, the final equation should be $(q - p)p^{l-1}+(q+1)(p-1)=0$ instead.

Comment: @JohnOmielan I was asking about Jack's claim in the first paragraph since i missed his assumption that $p$ is the smallest prime that divides $n$. But thanks for your time.